# How to embed and render an entityform

Tags: entities

I have an entityform called 'foia_generator' and I'm trying to embed it as a contact form on a page (the tutorial I used is for [embedding entityforms in blocks](https://www.drupal.org/node/2051513)) ... hence my problem...

```
function foiagen_form($form, &$form_state) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'entityform', 'entityform.admin');
    $entity_form_name = 'foia_generator';
    $render_estimate_form =
    entityform_form_wrapper(entityform_empty_load($entity_form_name), 'submit', 'embedded');
    echo drupal_render($render_estimate_form); 
    return $form;
}
```

This displays the form but it's not 'inside' the normal bounds of the site (using bootstrap subtheme) i.e. it's not rendered properly - it appears before the regular divs like the navbar etc... and spans the entire width of my screen.

If I can't do it this way can I programattically embed the 'entityform' on my 'contact page' as an entityreference field, (rendered)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I made to embed any entityform:

```
function my_module_entityform_form($form, &$form_state, $entityform_name) {
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'entityform', 'entityform.admin');
  $entityform = entityform_create(array('type' => $entityform_name));

  return entityform_edit_form($form, $form_state, $entityform, 'submit', 'embed');
}
```

And then you can call it using your specific entityform name as a Drupal form:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('my_module_entityform_form', 'entityform_name');
```

This is good because it uses [form_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) instead of [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7), so the validate and submit functions will also have access to entityform.admin.inc.

Comment: This is useful, but makes it tricky to use hook_form_alter as the $form_id will always be 'my_module_entityform_form'

Comment: I believe you could use hook_form along with drupal_build_form (or whatever it is) in order to create a variable form_id -- allowing unique form alters.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a odd piece of code you've got there, for instance this will render your form randomly in the page:

```
    echo drupal_render($render_estimate_form);
```

Which is probably what you're noticing already, that example you're linking is for render that piece of code inside a template but for what you describe you're rendering it in a form inside a block, I'd try something like this instead (untested):

```
function foiagen_form($form, &$form_state) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'entityform', 'entityform.admin');
    $entity_form_name = 'foia_generator';
    $render_estimate_form =
    entityform_form_wrapper(entityform_empty_load($entity_form_name), 'submit', 'embedded');
    $form['foiagen'] = $render_estimate_form;
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so is it the 'echo' that causes the form to be rendered before everything else? Is the code odd in other ways?

Comment: Yeah, that's it, the rest looks fine but you'll probably want to tweak the form for your specific needs.